# How to access all "assigned" with google classroom API

Tags: google-api, google-classroom

I'm new to the Google Classroom API, and would like to clarify if it is possible to access work from the "assigned" tab, or if possible, all the tabs in the image below. I'm using Javascript btw. Thanks!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEGsW.jpg 
(I need 10 reputation to post pictures .-. so here's the link)

Comment: If you're referring to the list of work created by a teacher for students of the course, you can use the method [`courses.courseWork`](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork). You can just check the possible modes of assigning coursework/announcements using [`assigneeMode`](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/AssigneeMode).

Comment: No I'm referring to all the work created by all teachers - essentially from all courses - which would be displayed in the assigned tab for students

Comment: In Google Classroom courseWork is always in the context of some course. So to get courseWork from all courses you will have to iterate through all the courses that the student has access to and for each course use this API- https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork/list. This API will give all Published assignment for that class for the student.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Google Classroom courseWork is always in the context of some course. So to get courseWork from all courses you will have to iterate through all the courses that the student has access to and for each course use this API- developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/…. This API will give all Published assignment for that class for the student.